# Snowflake - how to convert to a datetime stamp?

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a value of `1/11/19 10:25` and want to convert to `2019-01-11 10:25`

This works for converting 2-digit date to a regular:
`select to_date('1/11/19', 'MM/DD/YY') from dual;`
(result is `2019-01-11`)

But this did not work:
`select to_date('1/11/19 10:25', 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI') from dual;`
(result was `2019-01-11` without the time)

What is the correct syntax for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code:

```
select to_char(to_date('1/11/19 10:25', 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual;
```

I am casting to char to see the date results

You can check [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=66d6c85c722a19a74360e7b5d09d2327)

Comment: This is a Snowflake Database and result of a query above is `01/11/2019 00:00`

Comment: Okay... Can you try this code 
`select to_timestamp('1/11/19 10:25', 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI') from dual;`

Comment: The last SQL also includes seconds and milliseconds as zeros

Answer (score 0):

Since you have time in there, I'd go with TO_TIMESTAMP:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP('1/11/19 10:25', 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI');
```

which returns 2019-01-11 10:25:00.